# Typescript files to JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, build

I have project on express using typescript. When i try to use `tsc` to convert typescript files to `js` and create build folder, It's creating and everything is fine but when i try to start server in build folder am getting error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.`

Comment: Please check your package.json if your "type" key is using the "module" value.

Comment: If i use that then i can't start it in locale  "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn src/index.ts"'